# Mule : Queuemanager is null

Tags: java, mule, web.xml, mule-studio

I've created a java webproject and I'm trying to embed Mule into it.
All the required dependencies have been added to the pom.xml and snippet from web.xml is:

```
<display-name>Mule App</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.mule.config</param-name>
    <param-value>
         WEB-INF\mule-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The project has been configured to deploy on a Tomcat 7. 
When running the project it is giving this exception:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener
org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException: The required object/property "queueManager" is null
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:272)
    at org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.initialize(MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.java:96)
    at org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.contextInitialized(MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've tried doing it through Java using SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder, then creating muleContext and while trying muleContext.start() same exception is thrown. None of the ways is working.

This mule-config.xml works in Anypoint studio(it is just a basic one). I'm new to Mule so don't exactly know how to add things into queue manager.

```
<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.6.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="9900" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />
    <flow name="myFirstMuleFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP" />
        <logger message="Hello I logged" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
        <set-payload value="Payload set" doc:name="Set Payload" />
    </flow>
</mule>
```

I'm doing all this because if I deploy this project on a tomcat it opens up another port to which it listens because of the http listeners used. What I want is to be able to deploy a project on tomcat and everything executes on the same tomcat port.

pom.xml looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.muleConnector.csi</groupId>
<artifactId>mule</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-Alpha</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mule-embedded</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-embedded</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\mule-embedded.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId> org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.resource</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.resource-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.eaio.uuid</groupId>
        <artifactId>uuid</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
        <artifactId>grizzly-http-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.19</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>


    <finalName>mule</finalName>
</build>
```

Comment: Looks like your `mule-config.xml` does not define a queue manager. Can you add config file to your post?

Comment: Can you show the part of your pom.xml that has the Mule dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to define a queue manager by hand: Mule has one configured by default named `_muleQueueManager` and located in: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.6.1/modules/spring-config/src/main/resources/minimal-mule-config.xml#L37

The `minimal-mule-config.xml` is also loaded by default: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.6.1/modules/spring-config/src/main/java/org/mule/config/spring/SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java#L78

So there's something else at play here, something that prevents loading your Mule configuration.

Actually, it might well be this weird backslash here:

```
WEB-INF\mule-config.xml
```

This should actually be:

```
WEB-INF/mule-config.xml
```

**EDIT**: Also, this dependency is most probably the cause of the issue:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mule-embedded</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-embedded</artifactId>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
    <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\mule-embedded.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

You can remove it, remove whatever JARs you have in `${basedir}\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\lib` and instead use individual dependencies on `mule-core`, `mule-module-spring-config` and whatever extra modules and transports you depend on.

**EDIT 2** I've quickly whacked together an example showing how to run Mule in a web-app: https://github.com/ddossot/mule-webapp-example

Comment: I tried changing the backslash, it didn't work. I've added the pom.xml for your reference. Single mule jar file for embedding mule into java app has been added and no other dependency has been added. I tried adding mule-core dependency also, it gave another exception.

Comment: First time ever I see using `mule-embedded`. This thing, if it works, would bring all the transports and all the modules and all their transitive dependencies in your web-app. That can't be what you want. I've reviewed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks David. I've removed the mule-embedded jar dependency and added the mule-cole and mule-module-spring-config and other transport ones too. The exception is 
    SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener

Tried adding wrapper jar but don't know why this very basic project is not running. I even tried modifying the tomcat setup by putting in jars and mule-lib folders and modifying server.xml file with listener, but to no avail.

Comment: Trying to fix it, I did every step from this link http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Deploying+Mule+as+a+Service+to+Tomcat
and then tried to make it run. The tomcat couldn't even start then, had exception of argument type mismatch pointing to the listener line in conf/server.xml file that was mentioned as a step to follow in the mulesoft documentation.

Comment: Don't deploy Mule as a Tomcat service, this is too complex for no big benefit. Just deploy your Mule application as a WAR, it's much easier. `MuleXmlBuilderContextListener` is in the `mule-module-builders` artifact: is it in your POM (or brought in transitively).

Comment: @Shanky_Gupta People struggle too much with deploying Mule in a webapp so I've created this https://github.com/ddossot/mule-webapp-example to give a hand :)

Comment: Thanks a lot David. The previous suggestions for updating pom dependencies didn't fix the issue. However, this example looks to give a good headstart :) Will reply once I've made it work :)